Jest mocking issues
Whenever I am trying to mock the the async function declared inside a class using using jest.js in node.js. it is not the mocking the function instead it is going inside of its implementation. But the same thing is mocked from the other user for the same code. I don't know why?
I tried to mock the entire file and then used it inside in test but still it's not working.
Following is the js file for I want to write the jest code (eg)
Index.js
class MyClass {
constructor() {
    // Constructor code here
}

async fetchData() {
    try {
        // Simulating an asynchronous operation 
        // like fetching data from an API
        const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
        
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
        }
        
        const data = await response.json();
        
        // Some additional logic with the fetched 
        // data
        const processedData = data.map(item => 
            item.name.toUpperCase());
        
        return processedData;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error.message);
        throw error;
    }
}

}
module.exports = MyClass;
In this I was trying to mock the fetch data function like
Myclass.prototype.fetchData =
       jest.fn().mockReturnValue(1);

But instead of mocking the flow is going inside of its actual implementation.
So how to resolve the above issue?

Can you share a code example of your class and test\mock?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@TBA I have shared the code above.

Have you tried using jest.spyOn in order to mock fetchData function of MyClass:
describe("MyClass Test", () => {
  it("should fetch data from an API", async () => {
    const myClass = new MyClass();
    const mockFetchData = jest.spyOn(myClass, "fetchData");

    mockFetchData.mockResolvedValue({ test: true });

    const data = await myClass.fetchData();

    expect(mockFetchData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(data).toEqual({ test: true });
  });
});


Yes I have tried it , still it doesn't work
